# Why is Set at all required when we have Maps?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, set

Sets are essentially Maps from an existential point of view. There is nothing a Map can not do which a Set can, I assume. We have these overheads of defining key-value pairs in Maps which is not there in the Sets. But again the elements of a Set are just the keys of the underlying Map, right? So what is the point of having Sets around when Maps are able to do all the things required? I hope a Set takes the same amount of memory as a Map does?

What are key arguments in favor of existence of Sets?

For instance, in the case of Lists, we have ArrayList and LinkedList which have differences and we can choose between these two as per our requirements.

Comment: Sets don't need to be keyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that a `Map` is actually a `Set`!

`Map<Key,Value>` can be implemented with `Set<Entry<Key,Value>>`

This is similar to the mathematical foundations of what sets, maps, and functions are.

Firstly, can we agree that a `Map` is a function from `Key=>Value` (or `Domain=>Range`). Each key corresponds with at most one value, so it is a partial function (or a complete function only upon those keys in the map). So a map is a function. (Scala even goes so far as to have [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Map) implement the Function1 interface.)

Secondly, what is a function? [A function is a set of tuples where each first element occurs only once in the set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Alternative_definition_of_a_function). The second element of the tuple is the value returned by the function.

So we have `Map is a Function is a Set`.

---

On a practical note, there are very good reasons for having `Set`s. They are very often the correct data structure to use from a conceptual point of view, even before you start worrying about performance. I'd use them over a `List` in most situations.

Comment: Everything is a set. A list of cats is a set of `<Integer,Cat>` pairs, with the restriction that, if `X` appears as an Integer and is not  `0`, `X-1` also appears. I guess this is constructive set theory, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Many languages don't implement lists at all and instead use [associative arrays](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/), implementing lists as maps as you describe. And as maps are sets we should now quote Led Zeppelin _When all are one and one is all_

Comment: In order to use a `Set<Entry<TKey,Tvalue>>` as a `Map<TKey,TValue>`, there must be a query which, given an `Entry<TKey,TValue>` which reports itself equivalent to one in the set, will return a reference to the instance of that type which is stored in the set.  While there are many cases such a thing would be useful even when keys have no "values" other than the key objects themselves (e.g. an interning table), no such feature is provided in the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between a Set and a Map is that a Map  holds two object per Entry e.g. key and value and it may contain duplicate values but keys are always unique. But Set holds only keys and those are unique.

Comment: From his question, we can see he already knows that. He's asking why to use the Set data structure to begin with, when we already have Maps , that are just sets on steroids.